# Calculate surface area of flat figure by using double integral and polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

*Check me please. I tried check it via WolframAlpha, but I don't trust in it 100%.*

*Task:*

Calculate surface area of flat figure by using double integral in polar coordinates. Figure confined by line:

$$\left ( x^{2} + y^{2} \right )^{2} = a^{2}\left ( 2x^{2} + 3y^{2} \right )$$

---

My steps:

1. $x = \rho \cos\varphi , \: y = \rho \sin\varphi $
2. $\left ( x^{2} + y^{2} \right )^{2} = a^{2}\left ( 2x^{2} + 3y^{2} \right ) \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow
   \rho^{4} = a^{2}\left ( 2\rho^{2}\cos^{2}\varphi + 3\rho^{2}\sin^{2}\varphi  \right ) \Rightarrow 0\leq \rho \leq a\sqrt{2+ \sin^{2}\varphi} = A$
3. $\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\varphi \int_{0}^{A}\rho d\rho = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}A^{2}d\varphi 
   = \frac{a^{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (2+\sin^{2}\varphi))d\varphi = \frac{a^{2}}{2}\left ( 4\pi + \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1-\cos2\varphi }{2}d2 \varphi\right ) = 3\pi a^{2}$

Last integral in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20%5B0.5*a%5E2*(2%2Bsin%5E2(x))%2C%20x%2C0%2C2%5C%5BPi%5D%5D&t=crmtb01). I do not understand where is true :)

Comment: The Oval looks almost like an ellipse with semi-axes  √ 2 a, √3 a  
 but is different. The origin is an isolated point, needing to be isolated. Only a quadrant needs to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The shape is like an ellipse, only slightly bigger at $ \varphi = \pi/4 $ points. A lower bound for area is $ \pi \sqrt 6 a^2. $

To me your working & results seem ok, origin isolation is some bother.

Comment: Still do not undrstand your idea... Can you explain it via integral? (just with bounds of integration)

Comment: Trying to figure it out,my first hint was based on estimation of area without full calculation

Comment: I undrestand, that you did not calculate full and I do _not_ ask you for this. Just type bounds of integral if it possible :)

Comment: Did you mean $ 4 \int_{0}^{\pi / 2} d\varphi \int_{0}^{ a \sqrt{2+ \sin^{2}\varphi }} \rho d \rho $ ?

Comment: No need for this when your earlier was quite ok, I also get the same.